# Image.FromHBitmap for IPictureDisp to Bitmap in .net fails under Scheduled Task

Tags: .net, com-interop

I am converting a IPictureDisp to a Bitmap in a console app. It works beautifully when I run it on the server directly but when I run it from a scheduled task it fails with the error parameter not valid

```
Dim ipd As IPictureDisp = doc.GetPreviewBitmap(ReturnValue)
If ReturnValue = 0 Then
   Dim bm = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(ipd.Handle, ipd.hPal)
End If
```

I suspect it is related to [this problem](http://forums.asp.net/t/1718460.aspx) but I am unsure how to get around it. The scheduled task is running as me with the highest privileges box checked.

Comment: What is `GetPreviewBitmap`?

Comment: It is from a solidworks library dll that gets a document preview from a solidworks document.